# How do I put information on the flipped side of the page?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode

How do I put information on the flipped side of the page ?

Answer (score 1):

The ["utility application" template in XCode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/100-iOS_Development_Quick_Start/development_quick_start.html) creates a simple application with a main view and a flipside view; take a look at that to see and example of how the "horizontal flip" transition animation works.

Assuming you've defined a controller `FlipsideViewController` and your view is in a nib file named `FlipsideView`, you might do something like:

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];

controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

[controller release];
```